# Magento2: Impossible add discount code in checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, discount

We have any issue with approve discount code in checkout. In cart work correct and is possible add discount code.

I describe issue on movie below:
https://streamable.com/dq8io

Anyone know how to solve it or if no any solution any help how to disable discount form from checkout?

Comment: can you please share website url.

Comment: You can check here: czasowewyprzedaze.pl

Comment: Hello Syslvester these issue solve or else.sorry to be late reply.

Comment: r u on skype u can khirade.vijay id we discuss more

Comment: Vijay, Done. I have sent msg to your skype.